# How to adjust a table's width according to its contents regardless of the window's width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Normally, a table adjust it's size according to its contents. But when a table's appropriate width is larger than the window's width. the table seems to begin to adjust its width according to the window's width.

This table may adjust its width according to its contents:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this table may adjust its width according to the window's width, one cell's content may be broken into three lines:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
        <td>Blah blah blah.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to contain the table in a `<div>`, and set the `<div>`'s `overflow` to `scroll`, I can scroll to view the table if it's too big for the window to display. So how to make the table ignore the window's size and just adjust it's size according to it's content?

Comment: css `table{width: whateverpx}`

Comment: try adding the style `white-space:nowrap` to the `td`s

Comment: @Pete that's a complete answer, if you ask me.

Comment: Cool, you can mark martin's as the answer if you want - saves me typing it again!

Comment: @Pete Thanks, you wrote your comment while I was writing the same into the answer and jsfiddle. I guess great minds think alike ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `white-space: nowrap;` on the table cell contents.
This will prevent them from being broken down.

Here is a jsfiddle example of how you can then put it into a div
with scrollable overflow:

http://jsfiddle.net/VE4sU/17/